# SQL database with windows authentication

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, windows

I have installed my sql database with windows authentication, but now don't know how to connect to it.
The message I am getting is 
**Error**

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
/the database is on my local PC and I copied the path to it which is 
"C:\Users\MyName\Documents\My Web Sites\For evaluation-3col\App_Data\test.sdf"
```

so the command line is

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("C:\Users\MyName\Documents\My Web Sites\For evaluation-3col\App_Data\test.sdf")
```

or `die(mysqli_connect_error())`
I am a very new person to this and would really appreciate help.
Thanks

Comment: if its SQL Server try http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: if its MySQL (you have tagged both) http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: Thank you @Ganesh_Devlekar I've found it.  I can now get on with learning how to use MySQL and php